# Can't migrate table in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists. I want to migrate posts table. When I do this, see the above error.
Here is my users and posts tables migration code [posts migration code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bit03.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed your code but it seems your users table is already migrated. Assuming you are on localhost (no production development) you should try to run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

or if it won't help you should include your migrations code

Comment: I run php artisan migrate:refresh but it don't work for me.

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');